# Margin: auto still collapses on right when screen size shrinks

Tags: css, responsive-design, margin

I am building a responsive login page where everything has % widths. When I add a margin:0 auto, my main div is perfectly centered (as it should be), however when I shrink the browser size horizontally, I always lose the right margin or padding, regardless if it's set with a % or not. [Padding on right is cut off at smaller screen size](http://kevintomasso.com/img/screensize-issue.png) Here is a screenshot demonstrating the padding on the right getting cut off.

How can I force the margin or padding to always be honored regardless of the screen size?

==== UPDATE ====

I apologize for using the word "responsive" in this question. I do, in fact have media queries at different browser sizes for adaptive behavior, but my question is more simplistic than that. Before any media queries kick in, the right margin disappears when the browser shrinks. Something in my containing element must be throwing off the liquidity of the page. I cannot seem to figure out what this is. Any help is appreciated.

[Here's a link to the code](http://kevintomasso.com/amemberform.html)

Comment: do you think having % is responsive? do you have @media queries to manage the screen size? also show code so we can help you

Comment: @jycr753 Updated question with code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do based on the code you have right now:

```
.am-body {
    background: url("../img/body-bg.png") repeat-x left top #ededed;/*is being overwritten*/
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```